# Lambda Calculus - Inserting Parentheses?

Tags: parsing, lambda, lambda-calculus

This is a question from my midterm that I do not understand how to do.

Insert parentheses in to clarify how it's parsed

x y λx.x y

The answer is : ((x y) (λx.(x y))))

Could someone explain how you do that?

Comment: Have you written a program that does this? Which language are you using?

Comment: No, it's just a midterm question. Studying for final exams now. I think it's relevant to OCaml which we also did

Comment: So you want to know how OCaml would parse this text?

Comment: Whatever it takes to explain how you get the answer to the question

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, that is not the answer. `((x y) (λx.(x y))))` is invalid, it has one extra closing parenthesis.

( **( x y ) ( λx.( x y ) )** )  ) Note the imbalanced parenthesis

However, I will be ignoring that from here on out by assuming you meant: `((x y) (λx.(x y)))`, with the final parenthesis removed. I didn't mean to be nit-picking there, I believe this was probably just a typo, my IDE puts red lines under my code all the time for adding or neglecting to add a parenthesis by mistake, but I did think that this should be pointed out.

If the question was provided to you in this form without any other information, I will say that it is probably not very good, and it would have bothered me greatly if I saw it on a final, because there is some ambiguity in it. This could be solved in several valid ways that I can see, but the corrected version of the answer you provided is arguably the cleanest.

So looking back at `x y λx.x y`

Some syntactically valid, but non-equivalent possible ways of wrapping the variables could be:

- `((x y) (λx.(x y)))`
- `(x y)(λx.x)y` - is equivalent to `(x y)y`
- `x (y ((λx.x) y) )` - is equivalent to `x (y y)`
- `x (y (λx.(x y)))`

When approaching the problem, note that `λx.___` is the only completed abstraction. Therefore you know there will be an open parenthesis to the left of λ, and we have: `_x_ _y_(λx._x_ _y_`, some obvious pieces of intuition, based on the fact that the final solution must indeed be closed and balanced would provide:`(x_ _y_ (λx.(x_ _y)_*` where a `_` designates the possibility of one or more parenthesis, either open, or closed, see the `_*`, which could only be a closing parenthesis. Beyond this, the rest of the blanks can be filled in in any way so long as the parenthesis remain balanced.

My guess is that either:

- There was something more to the question left out here, like maybe you knew or could determine some example inputs and outputs, or were told to make the cleanest possible outcome (very subjective)
- This was a multiple choice question, and the other options could be ruled out. Perhaps they were not efficiently placing the parenthesis, including excessive wasted parenthesis, like in `((((x y) (λx.(x y)))))`. Perhaps they were plainly invalid, like `(x (y λx))(.x y)`. Or perhaps the parenthesis were unbalanced, as in your original claim of `((x y) (λx.(x y))))`, or a more exaggerated, less subtle `((x y)) (λx.(x y)))))`.

This would in my mind make a decent multiple choice problem, or with more information, a somewhat vague and open-ended, but not too terrible fill in the blank with more information provided. If it was given as is, I do have a problem with it, but maybe your professor would accept all valid answers that are formatted in a reasonable way. If the answer you provided, including the extra unbalanced closing parenthesis, is actually what he used as the correct one (perhaps in a multiple choice), then there is a bigger problem, because that answer is plainly wrong.

Sorry about answering this kinda late, hopefully the question is still useful to you, and hopefully if so this was of some help.